# How can I implement a setup with other setups in it?

Tags: setup

For my Python program, I want to generate a setup.exe file. However, in order for the users to use it, I also need to make them setup MySQL server to their computers. How can I do this as in the way DirectX is installed when we install games?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You will need to use an install creator, such as installshield, etc...

Comment: If they need to install MySQL you might provide it as a requirement rather than being part of the setup itself. MySQL can be rather complex to setup.

Comment: Then there's the question of whether you're allowed to bundle a MySQL installer according to their licensing, and whether it's a good idea to require a full database server on user machines in the first place... (What if they already have their own MySQL? What if they have MySQL because another program requires it?)

Comment: @grawity No, my intention is putting the installation of MySQL server as a tick item. Like the DirectX tick in the game installations. It won't be obligatory. Just an option in case their computer doesnt have it.